# Prove that P is a prime ideal of R if and only if R/P is an integral domain

Tags: ring-theory

I saw the proof of this a lot of books. In the proof it says that (a+P)*(b+P)$=P this is not true I guess below I explained why I am thinking like this

$5\mathbb{Z}$ is a prime ideal $2,3 \in \mathbb{Z}$,

$$ (2+5\mathbb{Z})\cdot(3+5 \mathbb{Z})=6+2 \cdot 5 \mathbb{Z}+3\cdot5\mathbb{Z}+5 \mathbb{Z}\cdot 5 \mathbb{Z}=6+10 \mathbb{Z}+ 15 \mathbb{Z}+25 \mathbb{Z}=6+5 \mathbb{Z} \neq \mathbb{Z}$$  what am I missing at this point ?

Comment: Until now everything is fine. What do you want to show with this computation?

Comment: I was going to writ 6+5Z$\neq$=5Z and I will edit now. (a+P)*(b+P)=P in the proof this fact is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple problems manifest here.

The first thing is that you’re multiplying cosets as if things had to be distributed. There is no cause to do that: coset multiplication is defined as $(x+I)(y+I)=xy+I$. The stuff you included with the cross terms is unnecessary.

Secondly, the last $\neq$ in your computation doesn’t make any sense. You are trying to equate a coset with $\mathbb Z$ inappropriately.

To fix it, $6+5\mathbb Z=1+5\mathbb Z\neq 0+5\mathbb Z\in \mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$.

So the hypothesis of checking primality doesn’t even apply to these two elements.

—-

> $(a+P)*(b+P)=P$

The best way to write this, IMO, is $(a+P)*(b+P)=0+P$, which is written entirely in terms of coset operations. It states that two elements are multiplying together to make zero in the coset ring.  Sometimes people omit the $0+$ in $0+P$, but I think that leads to some unfortunate misconceptions about equality, sometimes.